# Get Div Class data-files as php value

Tags: php, html

So, i have been trying to get the data-files as a php variable, but have not been able to get it.
This is from the source code.

```
<div class="videoplayer" id="video1" data-files="files.mp4">
```

This is the code im having most succes with, but i dont get the data-files value.

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
#$doc->loadHTML($url);
$doc->validateOnParse = true;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHtml(file_get_contents($url));
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);
$classname="videoplayer";
$finder = new DomXPath($doc);
$result = $finder->query("//*[contains(@class, '$classname')]");
// There's actually something in the list
if($result->length > 0) {
$node = $result->item(0);
echo "{$node->nodeName} - {$node->nodeValue}";
} 
else {
echo "Empty";
}
?>
```

Any ideaas how to achieve this?

Comment: what's the value of `$url`in `$doc->loadHtml(file_get_contents($url));`?

Comment: what is echoed?

Comment: If `DOMDocument` is anything like what I'd expect it to be, you could get the value from within that `if` statement like `$node->getAttribute("data-files")`. But, what do I know.

Comment: $url = 'http://www.dumpert.nl/mediabase/7349527/e5537593/waarom_schudt_die_trein_zo_3.html';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the value of attributes using [`DOMElement::getAttribute`](http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattribute.php). So to get the `data-files` attribute, use:

```
$file = $node->getAttribute("data-files");
echo "$node->nodeName - $file";
```